# Screengrabs with Python, incrementing the filename

Tags: python, file-io, screenshot

I'm using this code to make screengrabs on a Linux system with Python:

```
from gi.repository import Gdk

window = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
x, y, width, height = window.get_geometry()

print("The size of the root window is {} x {}".format(1920, 1080))

# get_from_drawable() was deprecated. See:
# https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch24s02.html#id-1.6.3.4.7
pb = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(window, 384, 216, 1152, 648)

if pb:
    pb.savev("screenshot.png", "png", (), ())
    print("Screenshot saved to screenshot.png.")
else:
    print("Unable to get the screenshot.")
```

What I would like to do is have Python increment the file name every time the program is run. So the first time the output file would be something like "screenshot0.png", the second time "screenshot1.png" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since your program is run from scratch each time, you cannot store the last screenshot index (and even if you could there could be a disrepancy between what's actually on disk and the stored counter)

You can, however, check if previous file exists and increase a counter until it does not, like this:

```
counter=0
while True:
    new_name = "screenshot{:04}.png".format(counter)
    if not os.path.exists(new_name):
        break  # file doesn't exist: we can use that name
    counter+=1

pb.savev(new_name, "png", (), ())
```

Note the `{:04}` format that will create `0001`, `0002` prefixes etc... so files are properly sorted in your file browser (better than plain `{}`)

the only drawback is that if you already have 10000 files in your folder, there will be 10000 successful file tests before you can create your new file.